# Get author id from url

Tags: author-template, users

I am trying to get the authors `user_id` on a page linked to by using `get_author_posts_url(),`.

For example

```
http://example.com/author/John%20Smith
```

where `John Smith` is `user_id` is `23`. I need to get `23`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On an "author" page `get_query_var('author')` will give you the ID.

`get_queried_object()` will get you considerably more author information.

```
$author = get_queried_object();
echo $author->ID;
// var_dump($author); // to see all of the information available.
```

For retrieving custom author data [follow the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Author_Templates#Custom_Author_Information).

Comment: I am getting a bool(false)

Comment: For which one? I tested both and they do work but this will only work on a proper "author" page which seems to be the case based on the URL you posted.

Comment: My apologies, it works. How can I access this within a plugin?

Comment: Saying "in a plugin" changes the context _a lot_. You will have to do more explaining, possibly start another question.

Answer (score 0):

First extract the nice name of the author from the author url, then you can get the author then you need to query the `wp_users` table like bellow.

```
$nicename =  "gowrisankar"; // example
global $wpdb;

$wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT ID FROM wp_users WHERE user_nicename = %s ",$nicename));
```